# Apply the same symbology to multiple raster layer

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, layers, symbology, import

I have many raster layers and I need to apply  same symbology to all raster layer. I used this code and the error was:

> Runtime error  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 8, in    File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.4\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 6438, in ApplySymbologyFromLayer     raise e ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid. ERROR 000968: The symbol layer does not match the input layer Failed to execute (ApplySymbologyFromLayer).

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = mxd.activeDataFrame
groupName = "New Group Layer_1"
lyrFile = "disp_2022081.tif"
allLayers = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, groupName, df)[0]
for layer in allLayers:
    arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management(layer, lyrFile)
    layer.visible = "True"
 arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
```

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: A TIFF isn't a layer file. You need to apply the layer of that source to the other layers.

Comment: Also you need to set lyrFile to be a full path to a valid layerfile.